# Connection Drop with Load Balancing over Multiple Uplinks

Tags: routing, load-balancing

I have a Server with to uplinks into the Internet. I'm doing load balancing over both uplinks with ip utility from the iproute2 package.

```
~ # ip route show
[...]
default
    nexthop via 217.0.117.212  dev ppp0 weight 50
    nexthop via 192.168.178.1  dev eth2 weight 50
```

If the server is under heavy traffic load then persistent connections like ssh or dowloads are simply dropped after some time. If I disable load balancing everything works fine, even under heavy load conditions.

Comment: the eth2 link implies NAT somewhere upstream, correct?  If so, how are you ensuring that packets sent out this interface have the correct source-address of the initial TCP connection?

Comment: Yeah there can be some issue with NAT most likely.

Comment: I'm not ensuring that at the moment, how to do this?

Comment: Hard to answer now... Please give us more details, such as a network diagram showing addresses / connectivity and how DNS is used to resolve to hostnames for this machine.  You might need to sanitize out quite a bit of material

Answer (score 1):

Following this guide my help you. He handles the NAT nicely.

http://sygard.no/2012/06/load-balancing-multiple-isp-connections-using-iproute-and-iptables/